# A hint changes query results. Why is this OK?

Tags: sql-server, hints, sql-server-2022

I have a query where OPTION(NO_PERFORMANCE_SPOOL) changes the resultset. I understood that hints affected the physical operations, not the values returned. I'd like help understanding why this is happening.

The context is generating dummy demo data. The schema is a typical Users -< Orders -< OrderItems >- Products setup. I only need Users and Orders to reproduce the phenomenon. Here they are, cut to what's needed.

```
create table dbo.Users(
    UserId      int identity(1, 1)  NOT NULL,
    UserName    varchar(50)         NOT NULL,
    
    constraint pk_Users
        primary key clustered (UserId),
        
    constraint uq_Users_UserName
        unique (UserName)
);

create table dbo.Orders(
    OrderId     int identity(1, 1)  NOT NULL,
    UserId      int                 NOT NULL,
    
    constraint pk_Orders
        primary key clustered(OrderId),
        
    constraint fk_Orders_Users
        foreign key (UserId)
        references dbo.Users(UserId)
);
```

Users is populated with 1,000 rows. I would like each user to have a random number of orders. My idea is to read Users for the foreign key, use an APPLY to return multiple rows per user, and generate a random number within the APPLY to control how many order rows there will be per user.

A search delivers a method of generating a new random number per row. I try this to check.

```
select
    u.UserId,
    o.Random
from dbo.Users u
outer apply(
    select ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 100 Random
) o
order by u.UserId;
```

This gives the expected output

```
UserId  Random
1       29
2       92
3       4
4       95
etc.
```

Happy days. So I flesh it out and check the distribution of orders per user.

```
truncate table dbo.Orders;

insert dbo.Orders(
    UserId
)
select
    u.UserId
from dbo.Users u
outer apply(
    select top(1 + ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 100)  -- 1 to 100 Orders per User
        1 dummy
    from dbo.Numbers
) o;

select distinct
    num_users = COUNT_BIG(*) over(partition by COUNT_BIG(*)),
    how_many_orders = COUNT_BIG(*)
from dbo.Orders o
group by o.UserId
order by num_users;

--Results
num_users  how_many_orders
1000       91
```

Oh dear. All users have the same number of orders. The plan shows a Row Count Spool (Lazy Spool). I realise my error - there is no correlation between the outer and inner branch. Fair enough. So I add OPTION(NO_PERFORMANCE_SPOOL) (for science!) and get the output I wanted.

```
select
    u.UserId
from dbo.Users u
outer apply(
    select top(1 + ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 100)  -- 1 to 100 Orders per User
        1 dummy
    from master..spt_values
) o
OPTION(NO_PERFORMANCE_SPOOL);

num_users  how_many_orders
4          61
4          84
5          11
5          38
6          3
etc.
```

But now the row count is different. Before it was a whole number of thousands (1,000 users * the random order count). Now the order count differs from user to user so the total number of orders is no longer a multiple of 1,000. It seems to me that this is a problem. A hint should not change the results returned, only the physical implementation. What am I missing here, why is this behaviour OK?

I've run on Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (RTM) - 16.0.1000.6 (X64) and also on SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU31-GDR) (KB5021126) - 14.0.3460.9 (X64) with the same results.

For the record, a non-hinted solution is to reference the outer table in the inner and the inner in the results.

```
select
    o.UserId            -- taken from the inner query
from dbo.Users u
outer apply(
    select top(1 + ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 100)  -- 1 to 100 Orders per User
        u.UserId        --references the outer query
    from dbo.Numbers
) o;
```

Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/8q73cTLb